# process Django NameForm data and use it as file name

Tags: python, html, django, forms

could someone please help me solve the following problem? It is mainly about how to get the django form data to be used to create a txt file. For example, if the user enters "Alex", a file should be created as Alex.txt.

I am trying to create a web app that an user can enter a name at the beginning(in a intro form) then make some choices (in an index form). At the end a file will be created to record the choices and  the file should be named as the name entered(in a complete form).  I am using the following code for defining the class in forms.py

```
class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your Name', max_length=100)
```

In the views.py I wrote

```
def intro(request):
.
.
.
    request.session['subjectname'] = []

    if request.method == 'POST':
    # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
    form = NameForm(request.POST)
    # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
        request.session['subjectname'] = form.cleaned_data['your_name']
        else:
        form = NameForm()
context = {'form': form}
return render(request, 'polls/intro.html', context)

def index(request):
...

def complete(request):
subjectname = eval(str(request.session['subjectname']))
filename = '{}.txt'.format(subjectname)
...
```

At the moment the file can be created but with an empty name, i.e., [].txt.

Comment: I can't imagine why you think you need to use `eval` there in the complete method.

Comment: hi it gives the same result without eval....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem by myself. It turns out when the form is passed with a 'get' method. so anything written in after

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

has not been executed.  That is why output txt file is [].txt.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a webapp and you want to save the user choices, you should be doing that using a database. As a starting point, I recommend looking into generic views. These will make your application much cleaner, and functional.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/

If you don't want an application with this much functionality, then moving away from django, and using flask may make your life easier.